# Make SSDP discovery on FMX (Android) Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to do SSDP discovery on a little FMX(Android) app of myself (to discover my ambilight server).
This is where I'm right now :

```
procedure TfrmHyperionManager.searchSSDP;
var
   _udpClient: TIdUDPClient;
   _peerPort: Word;
   _peerIP, _response: string;
begin
   lblServers.Text:= 'Recherche de serveurs Hyperion...';
   _udpClient:= TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
   try
      {$IFDEF ANDROID}
         _udpClient.Active := true;
      {$ENDIF}
      _udpClient.BoundIP:= GStack.LocalAddress;
      _udpClient.ReceiveTimeout:= 3000;
      _udpClient.Send( '239.255.255.250', 1900, 'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1' + #13#10 +
                                                'HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900' + #13#10 +
                                                'MAN: "ssdp:discover"'+ #13#10 +
                                                'MX: 3'+ #13#10 +
                                                'ST: urn:hyperion-project.org:device:basic:1'+ #13#10 +
                                                #13#10 );
      repeat
         _response:= _udpClient.ReceiveString( _peerIP, _peerPort );
         if ( _peerPort <> 0 ) then
            FServersList.Add( _peerIP );
      until ( _peerPort = 0 );

      fillServerCombo;
   finally
      _udpClient.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Now that works on my phone (Android 10), but it doesn't on some other phones...it is a bit of hit and miss, sometimes it works on a phone model (let's say Redmi Note 7) and it does not on the same model of another person...(app does not open).
Do I do it the right way ?
If not can you give me some example of how to do this properly ?
I'm sorry for this question but it is my first attempt at an Android app with Delphi, the rest of time I only do windows development with Delphi for my company.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please define "Doesn't work on some other phones".

Comment: They stay on the splashscreen for some, never display the app, and for some others, SSDP returns nothing (on the same network than the ones working).

Comment: Why are you setting `Active=true` at all? And especially *before* setting the `BoundIP`? Setting `Active` will allocate and bind the socket. `Send()` will allocate and bind the socket of not already, so using `Active` manually is redundant.

Comment: Like I said, first attempt to do this for me, and first attempt too at SSDP...
I found that snippet on a thread where you gave the solution btw, with active:= True...
http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/xe5-sure-that-indy-is-compatibl/1057505